# How to get parameters before child component initialization

Tags: angular

**The usual scenario**: User is presented with /login window. He logs in and get redirected to /dashboard, he may also load a list of other users at /users path. He then clicks on a user and ends up in /users/1 path. Selected users' data is now shown on the screen, as it was preloaded with the user list.

Parent component is "/users"
Child path is ":userId"

**Unusual, but possible scenario**: User goes directly to /users/1 path by pasting the url (login token still valid, so he is not required to login).

At this point we do not have loaded user list, nor selected users' data.

I use path resolver to load the user list. It loads the list before the path is opened.
The problem is with :userid child path. I can only get this parameter in child components constructor or Init methods.

This is not good, because each Component with child path has to extract that parameter and "select" the appropriate user from the list.

I want to have ability to select the user in a single place.

I have tried creating single resolver for each child path. This resolver tries to extract :userid parameter and then select it.
I have also tried to assign that resolver to parent path only.
I have also tried to create CanActivate guard, which should extract :userid.

None of these methods yield any result, because route[.snapshot].paramMap is empty.

I even tried to subscribe to paramMap of the route, but result is the same.

router file

```
{ path: '/users', component: parentComponent, children: [
        { path: ':userid', component: userComponent, resolve: { user: SelectUserResolver } }
        { path: ':userid/edit', component: userEditComponent, resolve: { user: SelectUserResolver } }
        { path: ':userid/show, component: userShowComponent, resolve: { user: SelectUserResolver } }
        ..... many more paths .....
    ]
}
```

resolver file

```
export class SelectUserResolver implement Resolve<any> {
    constructor(private userService: UserService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
    resolve() {
        let userId = this.route.snaphot.paramMap.get('userid'); //<- empty map
        this.userService.selectUser(userId);
    }
}
```

parentComponent

```
export class parentComponent {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        let userId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('userid'); //<- empty map
    }
}
```

userComponent

```
export class userComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
    ngOnInit() {
         let userId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('userid');// <- this works.
    }
}
```

I expect paramMap to have userId, but it is empty no matter what i do.
Accesing it inside child components is very bad, because i would need to repead this code for each component created.

Comment: I don't think you inject `ActivatedRoute` on your resolver. When you implement `Resolve` it should implement `resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)`. Which then you can access `route.paramMap.get('userid')`

Comment: Seems that `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` is not a provider, neither is `RouterStateSnapshot`, so it wont let me inject them. Router state snapshot can be retrieved by injecting `rotuer: Router`, then `router.routerState.snapshot`. But none of these seem to work in way i need it to. I still can't see parameters.

Comment: you don't inject `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` nor `RouterStateSnapshot`, those are the arguments for your `resolve(...)` function.

Comment: Thank you. Seems that RouterStateSnapshot is not required. Once i added `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` as a `resolve` function parameter, i could retrieve the value. Please post your answer, so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resolvers you don't inject `ActivatedRoute` to your constructor. As per the documentation: https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

When you implement `Resolve<T>` you can get the route from the method:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<T> | Promise<T> | T
```